# Is it possible to write a newline to a socket's OutputStream?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, io

I have a `Socket` that works well, but is it possible to write a `newline` to the `Socket` OutputStream?

This is what I've tried:

```
InputStream input  = clientSocket.getInputStream();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

out.write("Hello" + "\r\n");          
out.write("People");

out.flush();
```

Comment: How have you tried doing this already?

Comment: [After the edit] You are correctly writing the newline characters to the stream. Do any errors pop up or does anything behave unexpectedly?

Comment: No, but the client stuck in the `while(true){}` loop only reads the first line.

Comment: Then you should post the reading client's code as well - the error seems to be at the client side.

Comment: different OSes treat newline characters differently. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: @Ken : Do let me know, the real reason, as to why you want the newline ? Is it to make both the values reach the client side namely "Hello" and "People", since as you said your client side is stuck and reads only the first time.  Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"newline" is a *text-based* concept. An `OutputStream` is a *binary-based* concept.

If you're writing text to the socket, you should use a `Writer` of some description, e.g. an `OutputStreamWriter`. You can then wrap that in a `BufferedWriter` which has an appropriate `newLine()` method.

If you're *not* writing text to the socket, then "new line" doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: I messed with my client-side a little and used the OutputStreamWriter. Worked. :D